# Remove a "user / person" from Chrome desktop?

Tags: google-chrome

Currently under the "People" tab at the top i have a person that i added by mistake the "x - DNU" person in the attached screenshot. Any idea how i can delete this "user / person" from from Chrome desktop.

(Note this is not to do with closing a google web account)

[image: screenshot from chrome desktop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this works for macOS.
Most probably this is how you would do it in an active chrome window -

- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (macOS) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (others)
- Select *Manage People*

Or launch chrome with the guest profile command line argument.

```
chrome --profile-directory="Guest Profile"
```

Then you should see a grid consisting of user accounts in your Chrome browser.

In this grid, tap the three vertical dot icon in the top right corner of the person image, and select *Remove this Person*.

The grid of user profiles looks something like this -
[image: Chrome User Profile selection window]